# Python: Check if tuple contain only integers with while

Tags: python-3.x

I have a task to define a function contains_only_integers which takes a tuple as the argument and returns True is every element of the tuple is an integer, and false otherwise. I'm a bit stuck on why I get false every time.

I would use a for-loop, but the task asks specifically for a while loop.

```
def contains_only_integers(tup):
    while isinstance(tup, int)==True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `while isintance(tup,int)`, the function evaluates the tuple, not each element. To achieve what you want, you need to iterate over the tuple. An example below:

```py
def contains_only_integers(tup):
    for item in tup:
        if not isinstance(item, int):
            return False
    return True
```

If the code find any item in the tuple that is not an integer instance it will return False. Otherwise, it will return True.

## EDIT

As you said you need to use a `while` loop, there it is:

```py
def contains_only_integers(tup):
    i = 0
    while i < len(tup):
        if not isinstance(tup[i], int):
            return False
        i+=1
    return True
```

Comment: Don't use == False

Comment: use `if not isinstance(item, int):`

Comment: My professor actually wants us to do this using while loops, it's counter-intuitive to me because a for-loop is much easier. Would you know how to implement that?

Comment: @birds_the_word I've updated the answer to use `while`

Comment: That's genius, would it help to think of the 'i' more as a variable (like for a for-loop) or a base case (recursion)?

Comment: @birds_the_word the `i` is the counter, and yes, it's a variable, like in the for-loop, that goes from 0 to length of the tuple-1

Answer (score 4):

Mthrsj covered your problem and how to fix it but an alternative, perhaps more pythonic, way of doing this would be to use the builtin [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function.

```
def contains_only_integers(tup):
    return all(isinstance(v, int) for v in tup)
```

Comment: OP specifically want a while loop, but yes, this the right way

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Yeah, odd restriction that was added to the question later.

Comment: I'll keep this little snippet, it's pretty useful but I don't think I know enough to apply it on a regular basis.